# Laravel Model Restore Event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have 2 Models Users & Staff. They have one to one relationship with one another.

User.php 'hasOne' Staff
AND
Staff.php 'belongsTo' User

When I Soft Delete a User I want to soft delete Staff entry as well, I have achieved this using(Works Perfectly):

```
static::deleting(function ($user) {
    $user->staff()->delete(); 
});
```

Now I want to restore the staff when I restore the User for that I have tried using this(Not working):

```
static::restoring(function ($user) {
    $user->staff()->restore();
});
```

But this is not working. The User Entry is deleted but the Staff entry still remains soft deleted.

- Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?
- Also, Is this the best way to get this done? Or is there some other way this should be done?

**PS: I'm using Laravel 5.5**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"static::restoring" event is never triggered when restoring a batch of models.

If you're doing something like:

```
Yourmodel::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->restore();
```

It will restore your models but "static::restoring or restored" will never be triggered, instead you could do something like this:

```
$models = Yourmodel::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->get();
foreach($models as $model) {
   $model->restore();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It isn't working because `$user->staff()` doesn't fetch deleted staff. That's how relationships work by default.

Just replace it with this:

```
static::restoring(function ($user) {
    $user->staff()->withTrashed()->restore();
});
```

Comment: I believe, We don't have to use "withTrashed()" in Laravel 5.5. We can do it without it.